# An HTTP server that streams directories as zip files

Tags: web-server, http, server, zip

I'd like an extremely simple HTTP file server, whose sole function is to stream all directories under its root as zip files. Example:

`root/images/2022 Camping` contains a bunch of images. I run the server like this:

```
$ cd root
$ hzs 1080
***server is running. Does not return. Prints accesses.***
^C
$
```

That would start the server in the root directory on port 1080. To connect to it, you'd do (on a different computer):

```
$ curl 'http://host:1080/images/2022 Camping.zip' | bsdtar xf -
***curl output***
$ ls
'2022 camping'
$
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't stream a zip.

Comment: @Tetsujin : Try `bsdtar --format zip -cf - folder_to_compress | hexdump -c | less`. It does work.